# How can I place H_2 on top of a N ? (aspartic and glutammic metal complexes)

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

Please consider the following code

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{chemfig} 
\newcommand*\circleatom[1]{\tikz\node[circle,draw,fill=green!30]{\printatom{#1}};}

\begin{document}
\definesubmol{&}{-[:90,,,,draw=none]}
\definesubmol{8anta}{-[:-80,,,,draw=none]}

\setlewisdist{4pt}
\definesubmol{Gly}{
  H_{2}
  -[:-90]\lewis{0:,N}
  -[:225]H_{2}C 
  -[:-45]C(=[:-90]O)
  -[:13]\lewis{3:1:7:,O}!&\circleatom{Me}}
\definesubmol{Aspartic}{
  O=[:-90]C(-[:-25]\lewis{1:5:7:,O}!{8anta}\circleatom{Me}) 
  -[:230]H_{2}C 
  -[:-90,,2,2]HC(-[:30,,,2]H_{2}N)
  -[:-50]C(=[:-90]O) 
  -[:25]\lewis{1:3:7:,O}}
\definesubmol{Glutammic}{
  O=[:-90]C(-[:-25]\lewis{1:5:7:,O}!{8anta}\circleatom{Me}) 
  -[:230]H_{2}C 
  -[:-90,,2,2]H_{2}C
  -[:-90,,2,2]HC(-[:30,,,2]H_{2}N)
  -[:-50]C(=[:-90]O) 
  -[:25]\lewis{1:3:7:,O}}

\schemestart
\chemname{\chemfig{!{Gly}}}{Glycine}
\arrow{0}
\chemname{\chemfig{!{Aspartic}}}{Aspartic  acid}
\arrow{0}
\chemname{\chemfig{!{Glutammic}}}{Glutammic acid}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the second  and third molecules, I would like to show the electrons on N, but my attempts with the macro \lewis{...} were unsuccessful. Each time I insert \lewis near N, I always get a messed up molecule. I suspect I'm not writing the parentheses in the right place.

Also, I would like to write the two hydrogens over the N. I tried with a "phantom" bond (those named "&" in the manual) but I cannot figure out how to shorten only that bond.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\chemabove` and `\chembelow` may help :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\newcommand*\circleatom[1]{\tikz\node[circle,draw,fill=green!30]{\printatom{#1}};}
\begin{document}
\setlewisdist{4pt}
\schemestart
\chemname{%
    \chemfig{%
        H_{2}
        -[:-90]\lewis{0:,N}
        -[:225]H_{2}C
        -[:-45]C(=[:-90]O)
        -[:13]\lewis{3:1:7:,O}-[:90,1,,,draw=none]\circleatom{Me}
        }%
    }
    {Glycine}
\arrow{0}
\chemname{%
    \chemfig{%
        O=[:-90]C(-[:-25]\lewis{1:5:7:,O}-[:-80,.8,,,draw=none]\circleatom{Me})
        -[:230]H_{2}C
        -[:-90,,2,2]HC(-[:30]\chemabove[3pt]{\lewis{0:,N}}{H\kern1.5pt H})
        -[:-50]C(=[:-90]O)
        -[:30]\lewis{1:3:7:,O}
        }%
    }
    {Aspartic  acid}
\arrow{0}
\chemname{%
    \chemfig{%
        O=[:-90]C(-[:-25]\lewis{1:5:7:,O}-[:-80,,,,draw=none]\circleatom{Me})
        -[:230]H_{2}C
        -[:-90,,2,2]H_{2}C
        -[:-90,,2,2]HC(-[:30]\chembelow[3pt]{\lewis{0:,N}}{H\kern1.5pt H})
        -[:-50]C(=[:-90]O)
        -[:25]\lewis{1:3:7:,O}
        }%
    }
    {Glutammic acid}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: another solution with a slightly modifed version of `\chemabove` and `\chembelow` :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\newcommand*\circleatom[1]{\tikz\node[circle,draw,fill=green!30]{\printatom{#1}};}
\newcommand\stackabove[3][3pt]{\vbox{\offinterlineskip\vbox to0pt{\vss\hbox{\printatom{#2}}\kern#1}\hbox{#3}}}
\newcommand\stackbelow[3][3pt]{\vtop{\offinterlineskip\hbox{#3}\vbox to0pt{\kern#1\hbox{\printatom{#2}}\vss}}}
\begin{document}
\setlewisdist{4pt}
\schemestart
\chemname{%
    \chemfig{%
        H_{2}
        -[:-90]\lewis{0:,N}
        -[:225]H_{2}C
        -[:-45]C(=[:-90]O)
        -[:13]\lewis{3:1:7:,O}-[:90,1,,,draw=none]\circleatom{Me}
        }%
    }
    {Glycine}
\arrow{0}
\chemname{%
    \chemfig{%
        O=[:-90]C(-[:-25]\lewis{1:5:7:,O}-[:-80,.8,,,draw=none]\circleatom{Me})
        -[:230]H_{2}C
        -[:-90,,2,2]HC(-[:30]\stackabove{H_2}{\lewis{0:,N}})
        -[:-50]C(=[:-90]O)
        -[:30]\lewis{1:3:7:,O}
        }%
    }
    {Aspartic  acid}
\arrow{0}
\chemname{%
    \chemfig{%
        O=[:-90]C(-[:-25]\lewis{1:5:7:,O}-[:-80,,,,draw=none]\circleatom{Me})
        -[:230]H_{2}C
        -[:-90,,2,2]H_{2}C
        -[:-90,,2,2]HC(-[:30]\stackbelow{H_2}{\lewis{0:,N}})
        -[:-50]C(=[:-90]O)
        -[:25]\lewis{1:3:7:,O}
        }%
    }
    {Glutammic acid}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fine, thanks. I didn't noticed the "Stacking characters" in the manual. BTW, another question. I see that, for centering purposes, you are using `\kern1.5pt` between the two hydrogen. I would rather like to have in the figure an H_2. If I write it directly in the code, the H_2 is the non aligned with the N. I tried

`\,\,\,\, H_{2}`

so brute force, to obtain the desired results (`\quad` was too much).

Any other more elegant solution ?

Comment: Yes but you have to write your own macro to stack elements. See my edit.