# why bounding box dimensions are inherited from previous chemfig molecules in beamer?

Tags: beamer, chemfig, bounding-box

I'm sure my problem is related to my OS but I can't tell why and how.

Last year I was on Debian wheezy, while at present I'm on Mint Rebecca.

I'm revising my slides for the lessons and, after compiling the old ones on Mint (emacs/auctex to pdf) I found some differences respect to the slides I had last year.

I've canceled wheezy on my systems, so I cannot check the differences at the moment.

Consider the following (cleaned as much as possible) code

```
\documentclass[final, 10pt]{beamer} 
\usepackage{chemfig} 
\newcommand*\circleatom[1]{\tikz\node[circle,draw,fill=green!30]{\printatom{#1}};}

\definesubmol{&}{-[:100,.8,,,draw=none]}
\setlewisdist{4pt}
\definesubmol{Glycine}{
  H_{2}
  -[:-90]\lewis{0:,N}
  -[:225]H_{2}C 
  -[:-45]C(=[:-90]O)
  -[:30]\lewis{7:3:1:,O}!&\circleatom{Me}}

\definesubmol{EDTA}{
          HOOC-CH{_2}-[::-45,,1]
          {\lewis{4:,N}}
          (-[::-90,,1,1]CH{_2}-[::-45]HOOC)
          -CH{_2}-CH{_2}-
          \lewis{0:,N}
          (-[::45]CH{_2}-COOH)
          -[::-45]CH{_2}-COOH
        }


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \chemname{\chemfig{!{Glycine}}}{Glycine}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
 \chemname{\chemfig{!{EDTA}}}{EDTA}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Well, it is a simplification of [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104042/how-can-i-place-h-2-on-top-of-a-n-aspartic-and-glutammic-metal-complexes), but on Mint and as beamer document, the results are different.

The height of the bounding box of the "tall" glycine seems to be inherited by the "short"  EDTA one, which have the "EDTA" name very far from the molecule itself.

In fact, if you comment the line `\chemname{\chemfig{!{Glycine}}}{Glycine}` the EDTA caption switch back nearer to the molecule, to its proper place.

I can't add the pdf compiled last year, which I have saved, but I assure you that this beaviour was not present one year ago on wheezy.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here, but I can't see what !

Comment: The OS almost never makes a difference, You probably have different package versions. Sounds like you can not run on the old machine, but anyway add `\listfiles` to your document  probably you have some package with a recent date....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\chemname` sets the name below the compound depending on the depth of the compound *and the previous usages* of `\chemname`. The `chemfig` manual says:

> In fact, to draw the `<name>` the command `\chemname` inserts 1.5ex +
>   *the largest of the depths of the molecules thus far* below the baseline of each molecule [...]. The command `\chenameinit{<stuff>}`
>   initializes this largest depth with the `<stuff>`.

Technically this means that `\CF@dp@max` which is 0.0pt initially is updated *globally* with each usage of `\chemname` if the current depth is of `<stuff>` is bigger than the current value of `\CF@dp@max`.

The manual also tells the solution:

> Therefore one should:
>
> - write `\chemnameinit{<deepest molecule>}` before using the `\chemname` command in a reaction, unless the reaction begins with the
>     deepest molecule;
> - write `\chemnameinit{}` after having written all the names in a chemical reaction lest the greatest depth in this reaction interfere
>     with a future reaction.

The reason for this behaviour is to be able to have reactions with molecules of different depth where the names are aligned. This is done globally in order to enable alignment of the names also in schemes created with `chemfig`'s `\schemestart ... \schemestart` where compounds are placed in boxes (thanks to @unbonpetit for [explaining the background](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230663/why-bounding-box-dimensions-are-inherited-from-previous-chemfig-molecules-in-bea#comment545200_230693)).

Using `\chemnameinit{}` after the first usage of `\chemname` is also the solution in your case. Alternatively you can also use the starred version `\chemname*{...}{...}` for the second molecule. The starred version will not take previous calls into consideration but will also not reset `\CF@dp@max`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig} 
\newcommand*\circleatom[1]{\tikz\node[circle,draw,fill=green!30]{\printatom{#1}};}

\definesubmol{&}{-[:100,.8,,,draw=none]}
\setlewisdist{4pt}
\definesubmol{Glycine}{
  H_{2}
  -[:-90]\lewis{0:,N}
  -[:225]H_{2}C 
  -[:-45]C(=[:-90]O)
  -[:30]\lewis{7:3:1:,O}!&\circleatom{Me}}

\definesubmol{EDTA}{
          HOOC-CH{_2}-[::-45,,1]
          {\lewis{4:,N}}
          (-[::-90,,1,1]CH{_2}-[::-45]HOOC)
          -CH{_2}-CH{_2}-
          \lewis{0:,N}
          (-[::45]CH{_2}-COOH)
          -[::-45]CH{_2}-COOH
        }


\begin{document}

% first solution:    
\begingroup
  \chemname{\chemfig{!{Glycine}}}{Glycine}
  \chemnameinit{} % (un-) comment to see the difference
\endgroup

\chemname{\chemfig{!{EDTA}}}{EDTA}

% second solution:
\begingroup
  \chemname{\chemfig{!{Glycine}}}{Glycine}
\endgroup

\chemname*{\chemfig{!{EDTA}}}{EDTA}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Inside schemes, \chemfig commands are inside boxes (ie groups) and a global behaviour is necessary. For example `\schemestart
\chemname{\chemfig{A-[:-90]X}}{foo}\arrow(.base east--.base west)\chemname{\chemfig{B}}{bar}
\schemestop` displays "foo" and "bar" verticaly aligned. Without a global behaviour, it would not be.

Comment: Thanks to you all ! I (wrongly) assumed that within each `\frame` beamer environment a reset of all the chemfig parameters would occur. And in fact this was the case. I'm discovering that the behaviour is consistent: I have many other slides in which this discrepancy old/new occurs. I will seek for a wheezy box, and check which package versions are there. I was aware of the alignment within a reaction scheme, but in my past experience the subsequent frames were not affected at all.
Thanks again !!